# Oracle Apex: Region Not Hiding after Validation

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have two regions, the second one should show/hide if a field is empty or not.
I try different ways but after the validation the second region does not hide.

- Button validate field: search on the db if the value exists
- I the value exists populate a hide field(val_id)
- Dynamic action in the button if the val_id is empty hide the region

The validation happens but the regions does not hide:

[image]

Comment: What is the action on the button - are you submitting the page ? If so then this will not work as you expect. Please provide more details about your issue. What is "val_id" - is that a page item ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie yes, the button submit the page, :VAL_ID is a field in the second region, I populate or put null if the value on ESN is found or not. Also I validated the ESN field when button is clicked. That I want is also hide the region below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how apex works:

1. A page is rendered
2. a user manipulates the data on the screen
3. page is submitted and validations/processes are executed.

The doc will tell you this in more detail if you're interested. Dynamic actions allow you to declaratively add functionality in phase (2), because you need to have access to the DOM. Once the page is submitted (3) you cannot manipulate the DOM anymore so dynamic actions can no longer be used. In order to perform validations, you must submit the page.
Unfortunately I don't have an apex5.1 instance but the logic below should work for you.

There are 2 options to solve your issue

1. Use a dynamic action to perform the search. Set a hidden page item (for example P1_SHOW_DETAILS to 'Y' if results found and 'N' if nothing found. Then create a 2nd dynamic action on change of P1_SHOW_DETAILS with action show/hide
2. Don't use dynamic actions/validations. Use a page item P1_SHOW_DETAILS which is set in a page process after submit and branch to the same page with P1_SHOW_DETAILS value set in the branch. Then put a server side condition on the region to only render if P1_SHOW_DETAILS = 'Y'.
   In both cases you'll have to find another way to display the "ESN does not exist" message (you could use an alert region for that).

On a side note: you have a page item called "VAL_ID". It is a good practice to use the naming convention P<page_number>_. Page items need to be unique throughout the application and if you have to debug code where you're looking at "VAL_ID" how will you know what page to go and look. There are many other reasons but it's outside of the scope of this question.